# View SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am on WAMP configuration. Is there a way within WAMP or a package which will allow me to see SQL queries fired from PHP to MySQL server.

I am familiar with overriding DB adapters in JAVA to see the fired SQL requests. Is there something similar in PHP

OR is there a way to view the fired SQL from mysql functions itself?

Comment: I don't think there is anything in PHP itself that will do that, unless you log each query you run. A better option would be to investigate mysql logging and see if you can log all sql queries to a file - this might help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the WAMP tray icon, and click 'my.ini' in the MySQL menu.

Then, add the following in the [mysqld] section:

```
general-log=1
general-log-file = "C:\wamp\logs\mysql_general.log"
```

Finally, restart all services and your queries should be logged. This enables MySQL's [General Query Log.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are few things you can do.

First if you are using function wrappers (for example `query()` as a wrapper for `mysqli_query()`) then you can echo the query from inside it (or save it to log file).

Second, you could enable **General Query Log** in MySQL (not recommended on live servers, since it can take a lot of space very fast!). There you may find everything that mysqld has done. More at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Third, you could install mysql proxy, which would run between your scripts and mysql, and it could output everything sent to your database. More at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/

It all depends on what you prefer, and what is suitable for your situation.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: 1. Mysql-proxy, i get the below error : The application has failed to start because the side by side configuration is incorrect please see the application event log or use the command line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail

Comment: 2.wrapper query.. When we use frameworks, we are just limited to passing associative array information. So, don't want to change abstracted libraries for logging queries